# Rewrite a where in / intersect query to a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

Is there a way to rewrite my query into a join one.

The question I have to solve is: List the names of green items sold by no department on the first floor. Do not show duplicates.

```
select distinct itemname from xsale where deptname in (
    select deptname from xdept where deptfloor <> 1
)
intersect (
    select itemname from xitem where itemcolor= 'green'
)
```

I have been stuck at this exercise a couple of days now because the join statements don't make much sense to me even after reading about it. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: input and output expected ?

Comment: the same output and input as in query

Comment: Please give us more details about your schema, data tables..you're not helping much

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works for you

```
Select Distinct a.itemname from xsale a
INNER JOIN xdept b on a.deptName = b.deptName
INNER JOIN xitem c on a.itemName = c.itemname
Where b.deptfloor <> 1 and c.itemcolor = 'green'
```

Comment: replace existing select with this one
Select Distinct a.itemname from ...

Comment: use the following query: 

Select Distinct a.itemname from xsale a
INNER JOIN xdept b on a.deptName = b.deptName
INNER JOIN xitem c on a.itemName = c.itemname
Where b.deptfloor <> 1 and c.itemcolor = 'green'

Comment: this gave me an error but the solution by esat worked for me. Much thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query will help you about how to use  join statment for your query;

EDITED

```
select distinct xs.itemname from xsale xs
inner join  xdept xp  on xs.deptname=xp.deptname
where xp.deptfloor <>1
 intersect 
    (select xi.itemname from xitem xi where xi.itemcolor= 'green')
```

Comment: Your welcome , you can check the answer for solution to help the others

Answer (score 1):

I think you can express the logic as an `EXIST` and `NOT EXIST` query:

```
SELECT itemname
FROM xitem
WHERE itemcolor = 'green' -- all green items
AND EXISTS (
    -- exists a sale for that item
    SELECT 1
    FROM xsale
    WHERE xsale.itemname = xitem.itemname
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        -- not exists a department in those sales with floor = 1
        SELECT 1
        FROM xdept
        WHERE xdept.deptname = xsale.deptname AND xdept.deptfloor = 1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is often best to build your queries up step by step. So if we break the problem down:

**List the names of green items sold**

```
SELECT  i.ItemName
FROM    xitem AS i
WHERE   i.ItemColor = 'Green';
```

**Items sold by a department on the first floor**

```
SELECT  s.ItemName
FROM    xsale AS s
        INNER JOIN xdept AS d
            ON d.DeptName = s.DeptName
WHERE   d.DeptFloor = 1;
```

So now, you want all the items output by the first query, except for those that appear in the 2nd:

```
SELECT  i.ItemName
FROM    xitem AS i
WHERE   i.ItemColor = 'Green'
EXCEPT
SELECT  s.ItemName
FROM    xsale AS s
        INNER JOIN xdept AS d
            ON d.DeptName = s.DeptName
WHERE   d.DeptFloor = 1;
```

Then the final part:

**Do not show duplicates:**

```
SELECT  DISTINCT i.ItemName
FROM    xitem AS i
WHERE   i.ItemColor = 'Green'
EXCEPT
SELECT  s.ItemName
FROM    xsale AS s
        INNER JOIN xdept AS d
            ON d.DeptName = s.DeptName
WHERE   d.DeptFloor = 1;
```

An alertanative to `EXCEPT` would be `NOT EXISTS`, they will almost always result in the same execution plan, but I find `NOT EXISTS` is more flexible (you don't need the same columns in both queries):

```
SELECT  i.ItemName
FROM    xitem AS i
WHERE   i.ItemColor = 'Green'
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    xsale AS s
                    INNER JOIN xdept AS d
                        ON d.DeptName = s.DeptName
            WHERE   d.DeptFloor = 1
            AND     s.ItemName = i.ItemName
        )
GROUP BY i.ItemName;
```

Again to show an alternative, I have used `GROUP BY` rather than `DISTINCT`. In most cases these are semantically equivalent, but there are scenarios where `GROUP BY` will perform better (namely when a scalar function is involved - `GROUP BY` will remove duplciates first, and then execute the funciton on all remaining values, `DISTINCT` will execute the function first and remove duplicate results).

**[Examples on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b36389efb2b956c68805483a2b230dbe)**